# AAD Authentication with Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) not working for simple query via API

Tags: authentication, azure-data-explorer

I'm attempting to access Kusto via the API with Python (a "headless" script, in other words), and would like to use an AAD application for authentication. I'm specifically working with the sample code on https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-python/blob/master/azure-kusto-data/tests/sample.py, which attempts to query the Samples > StormEvents table on the cluster https://help.kusto.windows.net. I can run the query in the Kusto explorer just fine, but I'm getting "Caller is not authorized to perform this action" when trying to run the sample code.

I followed the instructions on https://kusto.azurewebsites.net/docs/management/access-control/aad.html and https://kusto.azurewebsites.net/docs/management/access-control/how-to-provision-aad-app.html to create an AAD application on the Azure portal and add API permissions for Azure Data Explorer. In the code, I have the "Application (client) ID" from the portal in the client_id field, and the appropriate secret in the client_secret field. The authority_id field is set to 72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47, which is what's shown on the portal as well as the table on https://kusto.azurewebsites.net/docs/management/access-control/aad.html#authenticating-with-aad-programmatically The app name (and client ID) is accepted on https://www.analytics.msftcloudes.com/support/directory just fine.

The code is thus as follows (omitting the imports and the specific secrets):

```py
cluster = "https://help.kusto.windows.net"

client_id = "<omitted>"
client_secret = "<omitted>"
authority_id = "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47"

kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_application_key_authentication(
    cluster, client_id, client_secret, authority_id
)

client = KustoClient(kcsb)
db = "Samples"
query = "StormEvents | take 10"
response = client.execute(db, query)
```

The failure output is:

azure.kusto.data.exceptions.KustoServiceError: (KustoServiceError(...), [{'error': {'code': 'Forbidden', 'message': 'Caller is not authorized to perform this action', '@type': 'Kusto.DataNode.Exceptions.UnauthorizedDatabaseAccessException', '@message': "Principal 'AAD app id=(omitted)' is not authorized to access database 'Samples'.", '@context': {'timestamp': '2019-06-05T19:39:17.3493255Z', 'serviceAlias': 'HELP', 'machineName': 'KEngine000000', 'processName': 'Kusto.WinSvc.Svc', 'processId': 18832, 'threadId': 25568, 'appDomainName': 'Kusto.WinSvc.Svc.exe', 'clientRequestd': 'KPC.execute;9ede2b2d-5fba-478c-ad8f-8306284cf6e9', 'activityId': 'efdb96c9-da46-4d5f-b739-54661e7002e3', 'subActivityId': '33f89e2b-2347-447a-abe9-81e586d0e2a0', 'activityType': 'DN-FE-ExecuteQuery', 'parentActivityId': '438b2bb3-26fb-4f7e-813d-bc8a5c39ce1c', 'activityStack': '(Activity stack: CRID=KPC.execute;9ede2b2d-5fba-478c-ad8f-8306284cf6e9 ARID=efdb96c9-da46-4d5f-b739-54661e7002e3 > KD-Query-Client-ExecuteQueryAsKustoDataStream/5ddd9239-e742-4edc-ab3e-55d59a1f2c99 > P-WCF-Service-ExecuteQueryInternalAsKustoDataStream--IClientServiceCommunicationContract/438b2bb3-26fb-4f7e-813d-bc8a5c39ce1c > DN-FE-ExecuteQuery/33f89e2b-2347-447a-abe9-81e586d0e2a0)'}, '@permanent': True}}])

I've also added the sample cluster in Kusto Explorer, like the docs say.

Am I still missing something?

Answer (score 4):

https://help.kusto.windows.net is the URL of an ADX cluster which is an exploratory aid, and only allows interactive access by AAD users (not AAD applications).

for running automation using AAD application authentication, you should redirect your code at your own cluster/database, on which you grant your AAD application the necessary permissions (database user/viewer)

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know, because the sample doesn't indicate that limitation because it provides code for all three authentication techniques. I'll check with the cluster admin to get permissions for the AAD application.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. the sample should be updated to include this comment